# Why will "await" break or kill a for-loop in modern Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following function. It gets an array of attributes and will iterate over them in a loop to put every single attribute into a database. But the loop will be killed automatically with the `await` statement:

```
async function importAttributeRecords(attributeValues, languageId, attributes, dataStorage, tx) {
  for(let attr of attributes) {
    console.log("Persist", attr)
    try {
      await importAttributeRecord(attributeValues, languageId, attr, dataStorage, tx) 
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("After persisting");
  }
}
```

The first call to `await` will be executed, but the second `console.log` statement after it will never appear.
Also, the loop will be exited immediately.

How can I execute a function like my `importAttributeRecord()` in a loop synchronously even if returns a promise?
And why is using "await" dangerous for Loops?

Comment: Do you mean with the second log call the one outputting: `"After persisting"`? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: The loop isn't killed. It is put on hold and will resume when you `await` the promise. Promises are asynchronous. You can't treat them as synchronous.

Comment: It `importAttributeRecord` returning a promise? You may never resolve that promise.

Comment: without the code for `importAttributeRecord` it's impossible to say exactly what you've done wrong, because the problem is most likely with that function

Comment: @delete Is the answer offered below any use to you? If not, please comment and I'll be happy to refine. If it is, you could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

This could be described as a "category error". A `for` loop is fundamentally a synchronous-programming idea, doing each thing within (typically) an array or other indexed entity, one after the other, waiting each time.

Asynchronous programming, which `async` implements, is a different approach. The most perfect way to use it is just to express a relationship between the before-situation and the after-situation, and let the language take care of timing and possibly executing concurrently or in parallel.

For this situation, here is how you would do it:

```
async function importAttributeRecords(attributeValues, languageId, attributes, dataStorage, tx) {
  return Promise.all(attributes.map(attr => {
    console.log("Initiate persist", attr);
    return importAttributeRecord(attributesValues, languageId, attr, dataStorage, tx).then(result => {
      console.log("After persisting", attr, result);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error: ", attr, err);
    }));
  });
}
```

You will note that `importAttributeRecords` now returns an array of Promises, so it is legitimately `async`. You will also see this code is slightly shorter!

Comment: 1. Nothing in this example waits for the promises from `importAttributeRecord` at all. Did you forget `Promise.all`? 2. There's nothing wrong with the code in the question. Using `await` in a loop may not be advised because it'll run in serial, but that doesn't mean it won't work. Whatever's breaking the OPs code will break your code too. A `for` loop is fundamentally _serial_, but it is not fundamentally _synchronous_.

Comment: @loganfsmyth 1. Who says the caller of this doesn't want to use `Promise.race`? Did you forget that possibility? Additionally, are you saying you think returning the result of a `.then` is not idiomatic and compatible with `async`? 2. Are you saying that you think *serial* is idiomatic with *asynchronous*?

Comment: "Who says the caller of this doesn't want to use Promise.race" Because the original question has a loop that very clearly executes each item, waiting for them all. My point is `return attributes.map(` returns an array of promises, without waiting for any of them to finish, where the original code very clearly only returns from the function once all the promises are done. 2. In your question you say "for loop is fundamentally a synchronous-programming idea" which is not right, my point is loops define ordering behavior. Code can be synchronous or asynchronous independent of loop usage.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think you're probably right that `Promise.all` is the idiomatically closest to the "for loop" concept. I'll edit my answer and would be grateful for your thoughts on it. I think my last comment was a bit unnecessarily snippy, and my only excuse is that I perceived your initial comment as quite snippy (even though I'm sure that's not how you meant it). Separately, the lack of MCVE from the question somewhat impedes us in providing the most future-useful answer here.